# JPA/Hibernate maintain a lot of queries in memory on application startup

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I realized recently that an application is consuming more memory than it should. I made a thread dump of the JVM and found that there were hundreds of megabytes of SQL queries in Hibernate SessionFactoryImpl.

These queries arise in memory just starting the application server. I already discarded the hypothesis of a queue (JMS) or some other process in the background.

The queries are in this 2 formats:

```
select
diferenc0_.id as id975_137_,
[...]
where diferenc0_.id=?
```

Or

```
select
diferenc0_.id as id975_137_,
[...]
where diferenc0_.id= IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) -- because default_batch_fetch_size = 8
```

My persistence.xml configurations (I turned off hbm2ddl):

```
"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", ""
"hibernate.query.startup_check", "false"
"hibernate.show_sql", "false"
"hibernate.format_sql", "false"
"hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session", "true"
"hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false"
"hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "false"
"hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "20"
"hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size", "8"
```

I'm using Hibernate 3.3.0.

Another important detail: these queries are not sent to the database! I analyzed with the DBA of our team the query sent to the database when the Jboss is starting. We also **not use named queries** in the system.

As is an application a little old, the old developers used the fetch EAGER resource in mapping. So these generated queries are really huge.

Question: For what purpose Hibernate creates these queries in memory when the application starts?

Comment: Hibernate is famous for making extra/useless query (expecially with EAGER fetching), but at least it launches them by an application input, not by himself. Are you sure that your application doesn't contain timer, scheduled job or something that launch a query via Hibernate on startup and/or after a fix amount of time?

Comment: Hi! I'm sure. As I said, this queries are not even send to the database. This seems something like the `hibernate.query.startup_check` can do, but I already set this option to false.

Comment: Could you post your hibernate/persistence configuration file?

Comment: @Baldurian, I update the question with the persistence file and Hibernate version (3.3.0, very old).

Comment: Related: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=995325

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this property:

```
"hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults","false"
```

And remove

```
"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", ""
```

Comment: I will test in the next monday :).